# Image behind image/sidebar

Tags: html, image, positioning

I recently made a navbar, but I  want to put the part on the sidebar behind the sidebar title/image

The site is: http://testcheww.blogspot.com

i.imgur.com/vicR2fn.png

this is the part on the sidebar:

```
     <div style='height: 86px; width: 52px; border: 0px; margin-top: -172px; margin-left: 470px;'><img height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/quests-support.png' width='52px'/>
      </div>
    </center>
        <center>
<div class='supportbutton' style='position:relative; left:334px; top:-86px; margin-bottom: -82px;'>
<a href='http://www.tinkatollidunes.com/p/support-us.html'> <img alt='' class='a' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/support.png' width='152px'/> <img alt='' class='b' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/supporthover.png' width='152px'/> 
</a> 
</div>
    </center>
    <center>
      <div style='height: 86px; width: 52px; border: 0px; margin-top: -172px; margin-left: 874px;'><img height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/support-play.png' width='54px'/>
      </div>
    </center>
        <center>
      <div style='height: 86px; width: 142px; border: 0px; margin-top: -86px; margin-right: -1021px;'><a href='http://www.tinkatolli.com/play/'><img height='86' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/play.png' width='142'/></a>
      </div>
```

Comment: Confused about what you're trying to do. Do you want the sidebar to sit on top of the navigation bar? What have you tried so far?

Also you shouldn't use inline styles.

Comment: I want the support and play buttons to be behind the guides part (you see the text is covered by the buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just get rid of **margin-top: -25px** in your **#sidebar-wrapper** style...

[image]

Your CSS currently looks like this:

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
float: right;
margin-right: 21px;
margin-top: -25px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 315px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Change it to this:

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
float: right;
margin-right: 21px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 315px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Sure, and as other people are pointing out you're doing things in a very awkward way.  But I'd rather answer your immediate question than try to steer you towards best-practices.  Sometimes learning little by little is the best way.  Good luck.